# Queueing many requests and then sorting based on time added, but items end up sorted based on when they get received from request

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, afnetworking, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) and using an operation queue (similar to NSOperationQueue) to queue a bunch of requests to the [Clear Read API](http://api.thequeue.org/v1/).

I basically have an array of URLs, and I create individual requests based off of each of them, enqueue each request then batch execute the requests. They come back, one at a time, I timestamp then, then add them to Core Data which is the source for my table view, so the table view gets populated.

Only, the timestamp is issued when the item has successfully returned. This means the items are sorted based on when they're returned instead of in the order of the original URLs array. So the requests that take shorter times to return (less text for the API to process) are timestamped earlier and thus considered older than the items that are timestamped later due to being larger amounts of text. This is obviously not the case in terms of correct ordering.

In the end, even though I have the array of URLs for the API calls in proper order, my table view gets sorted based on when the API returned the item.

Here's my code:

```
- (void)addArticlesFromURLs:(NSArray *)URLs fromSource:(NSString *)source {
    // Restrict amount of operations that can occur at once
    [[AFClearReadClient sharedClient].operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:3];

    // Create an array to hold all of our requests to make
    NSMutableArray *requestOperations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSString *URL in URLs) {       
        // Create the request from the article's URL
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFClearReadClient sharedClient] requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/v1/clear?url=%@&format=json", URL] parameters:nil];

        // Create the request operation and specify behaviour on success and failure
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFClearReadClient sharedClient] HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                                                            // Get the item NSDictionary from the JSON responseObject
                                                                            NSDictionary *item = [responseObject objectForKey:@"item"];

                                                                            // Get the values needed to create an article
                                                                            NSString *title = [item objectForKey:@"title"];
                                                                            NSString *URL = [item objectForKey:@"link"];
                                                                            NSString *body = [item objectForKey:@"description"];

                                                                            // Replace HTML entities with their actual characters
                                                                            title = [title stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&"];

                                                                            // Remove all HTML and formatting from body so only plain-text remains
                                                                            body = [self removeHTMLAndFormatting:body];

                                                                                // Add it to CoreData if there's actual content (easiest way to tell is checking body)
                                                                            if (![body isEqualToString:@""]) {
                                                                                NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
                                                                                ArticleInfo *articleInfo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ArticleInfo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                                                                                articleInfo.source = source;
                                                                                articleInfo.body = body;
                                                                                articleInfo.title = title;
                                                                                articleInfo.url = URL;
                                                                                articleInfo.timeStamp = [NSDate date];

                                                                                NSError *error;
                                                                                [context save:&error];
                                                                            }
                                                                      }
                                                                      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                                            NSLog(@"Request operation error: %@", error);
                                                                      }];

        // Save the request operation in an NSArray so all can be enqueued later
        [requestOperations addObject:requestOperation];
    }

    // Enqueue the request operations
    [[AFClearReadClient sharedClient] enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:requestOperations progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
}
```

How would I go about altering this so that my tableview has the items in their correct (newest on top) order?

Answer (score 2):

Use `userInfo`.

`AFHTTPRequestOperation` subclasses `AFURLConnectionOperation`, and `AFURLConnectionOperation` declares a `userInfo` dictionary that passes through without being touched. Its purpose is to let you add whatever data you need for use when the operation completes. Before you add your operation to the queue, do something like:

```
[requestOperation setUserInfo:@{ @"timestamp" : [NSDate date] };
```

Get this in your completion block as

```
NSDate *timestamp = [operation userInfo][@"timestamp"];
```

The timestamps will reflect the order in which operations were added to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

I don'y really know `AFNetworking`, but ...

You could just take the timestamp prior to creating the request (in the for loop):

```
NSDate* stamp = [NSDate date];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = ...
```

Then in the operation success block:

```
...
articleInfo.url = URL;
articleInfo.timeStamp = stamp;
...
```

The block will retain you timestamp and set it on success